# QComboBox highlight breaks when disabling "Editable"

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, highlight, qt-designer, qcombobox

When i set a QComboBox to be non editable the item highlighting breaks.
more specifically, whenever i hover my mouse on an item, a white rectancgle hides all the item, and i essentially cant see what is the item i am hovering on. when i change the object to be editable, the hovering works ok.

Anybody have any idea how i can fix this bug on my end? is non editable inherently different class than editable QComboBox which causes this weird collision?

I am using QT designer to generate the UI code, and then i use pyuic.exe script to convert the .ui to .py code. I do not edit the .py code.

I am using version PyQt5

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
the following is the section inside the resulting .py file regarding this specific object:

```py
    self.block_list = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.monitors_groupBox)
    self.block_list.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 401, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Comfortaa")
    self.block_list.setFont(font)
    self.block_list.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
    self.block_list.setMouseTracking(False)
        
    self.block_list.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
    self.block_list.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.block_list.setStyleSheet("")
    self.block_list.setEditable(False)
    self.block_list.setObjectName("block_list")
```

Comment: Maybe you did set some stylesheet? Please share the ui file.

Comment: It would be problematic for me to share the whole ui file,  but i looked on the .py file that is generated after the pyuic.exe script and is the one actually run. i didn't find anything out of the ordenery regarding this specific object, neither inside the QT designer the stylesheet is default. i also created a new default QComboBox and the same happend with it too.

Comment: Try with a completely new UI and just a combo, do *not* change anything, then test it with the preview in Designer to see if the problem still persists from there; if it doesn't, and running the pyuic code instead does, add this line to that file `print(QApplication.style().objectName())` and also report your versions of both Qt and OS. If, otherwise, the problems doesn't happen, then it's something in your UI, and we cannot know if we don't have a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante when i use the review feature of Qt Designer, it seems to work fine, so i suspect the issue starts in the compilation to python with pyuic.exe script or something beyond.
printing QApplication gives me "fusion"

`Qt version: 5.13.2 |
PyQt version: 5.13.2 |
OS version:  CentOS Linux 7 (Core)`

Comment: pyuic doesn't change anything in the UI parameters, it just "converts" it to python commands. So, do you confirm that even with a brand new UI file and a simple qcombobox, the issue exists? Can you provide screenshots of the result (with and without the mouse over)? Do you use the default system colors or did you change some settings?

Comment: So when i create a brand new UI, the issue doesn't appear.
I guess this narrows it down that somewhere in the code i change the style. i inhereted this code from a previous employee but as far as i know he didn't change the style.
Do you have an idea of what kind of variable or name i should search that could change such specific style? sharing minimal reproductive example is kind of problematic since its about 2000 lines of code on the main and another 4000 lines of code on the ui.py file with company IP intertwined in it

Comment: Style sheets can be set to any widget, and are always inherited by their parents. You have to browse from the top level widget and pass through any parent of that combo and see all stylesheets those widgets have, because that combo will inherit *all* properties set up to its level (as long as they are relevant for it). Probably, that previous employee has set some generic property without proper selector (something that should always be avoided for widgets that can be parents). Unfortunately, without any code, it's really impossible to help you in any way.

Comment: What you can do is to remove *all* the other widgets except for the combo and its parents, and including *siblings* of those parents: for instance, if the combo is in a frame A, within a groupbox X that also contains a frame B, you can safely remove that frame B, as it has no direct relation, and only frame A could have any property that affects the combo; if the combo is in a tab widget, remove all other tabs; etc. Obviously, do that in a *copy* of the original file, then save it and share it (not the pyuic, the ui!) in your question.

Comment: @musicamante thank you very much! i found the issue just as you suspected. for some reason it didnt solve the bug when i only commented out the style sheet which caused me to delete everything until i started adding back stylesheets to find out it was all along this simple style in the main window that did all the trouble. right under my nose all along.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being a stylesheet entry in the MainWindow that trickled down all the way to affect all QComboBoxes. the simple entry was:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

This causes the QComboBox to become completely white when hovering on it with the mouse.

Sidenote:
The reason i was not able to reproduce the issue when using Qt Designer Preview mode is that i had to select Preview in Fusion, which is not the default way, and only in Fusion does this bug occurs.
Thank you @musicamante for your guidence and assistance

Comment: That's another reason for which generic style sheet properties should *always* be avoided (unless you *really* know what you're doing) when set for widgets that are likely to become parent - which is implied for windows. Complex widgets like QComboBox and scroll areas (item views, text edits, etc) always require carefully written QSS, and most issues arise when generic properties are set for them or in their parent tree. I know that wasn't your fault, but take this as an important experience: 99% of the times, you should use [selectors](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

Comment: thanks for all the assistance, even though this code was left by a previous employee, i can see how i would have done the same mistake, especially since Qt Designer pretty much incourages it by how easy it is to do, and we dont come from a Frontend background so our naive minds fall for this easly :D